# How to merge multiple polygons with Boost.polygon?

Tags: c++, boost, intersection, polygons, boost-polygon

I would like to merge a polygon with a set of polygons with Boost.polygon.

[image: Merge A, B and C]

For example merging the polygon C to the set (A, B) from the above picture would give the following result:

[image: Result]

How can I do that?

I thought about adding each polygons to a polygon set (`polygon_set_data`), and perform a XOR and an AND operation between the polygon set and the polygon to add.

The problem is that when I want to retrieve the result of my polygon set, all overlapping polygon are merged, resulting in a single polygon.

Comment: I think `intersect_segments()` of the [segment concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_segment_concept.htm) does what I want, although I would have to reconstruct the polygons myself. Is there a good way to reconstruct the polygons?

Comment: I talk about polygons in [Boost.polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm).